# How can I make this absolute html tag appear in front of an a relative tag?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me how I can have the popup appear above the header?

Why does this html token hide under the Header Tag?

I've tried using z-index with no success.

```js
function revealPopup(id){
  document
  .getElementById(id)
  .classList
  .toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.header {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}

.chat {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.line {
  z-index: 3;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  text-align: left;
  visibility: visible;
}

.bubble {
  z-index: 4;
  background: #ff0000;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  min-width: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: box-shadow 2s;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popuptext {
  z-index: 5;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 20%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popuptext.show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h3>
      Header
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="line">
      <div class="bubble">
        <span class="popuptext" id="popup">A Simple Popup!</span>
        <div class="message" onclick="revealPopup('popup')">Click Me</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="bubble">
        <span class="popuptext" id="popup2">A Simple Popup!</span>
        <div class="message" onclick="revealPopup('popup2')">Click Me</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML has a perfectly good `<header>` element. There's no need to fake one with class names.

Answer (score 1):

`.bubble` is `position: relative` so it creates a new stacking context. Since `.popuptext` is inside `.bubble` the z-index you set on it is *with respect to `.bubble`*.

You need to set the `z-index` on `.bubble` (since it shares a stacking context with `.header`).

Comment: setting a z-index didn't help it work :(  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found it,

The overflow stops it escaping `.chat`.

```
.chat {
    ...
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    ...
}
```